# Ошибки при попытке использовать команды Discord.Net

Tags: c#, discord, бот

Я начал писать бота для дискорда, используя шаблон. Но сразу столкнулся с проблемой неработоспособности команд. А именно, при их использовании в консоль выводится сообщение об ошибке такого типа:

```
fail: Discord.Commands.CommandService[0]
      Command:
      Discord.Commands.CommandException: Error occurred executing "echo" for ?MyName?#8766 in ThisServer/talk.
       ---> Discord.Net.HttpException: The server responded with error 401: 401: Unauthorized
         at Discord.Net.Queue.RequestBucket.SendAsync(RestRequest request)
         at Discord.Net.Queue.RequestQueue.SendAsync(RestRequest request)
         at Discord.API.DiscordRestApiClient.SendInternalAsync(String method, String endpoint, RestRequest request)
         at Discord.API.DiscordRestApiClient.SendJsonAsync[TResponse](String method, String endpoint, Object payload, BucketId bucketId, ClientBucketType clientBucket, RequestOptions options)
         at Discord.API.DiscordRestApiClient.CreateMessageAsync(UInt64 channelId, CreateMessageParams args, RequestOptions options)
         at Discord.Rest.ChannelHelper.SendMessageAsync(IMessageChannel channel, BaseDiscordClient client, String text, Boolean isTTS, Embed embed, AllowedMentions allowedMentions, MessageReference messageReference, MessageComponent components, ISticker[] stickers, RequestOptions options, Embed[] embeds, MessageFlags flags)
         at BH_Support_0._0._1.Modules.General.Echo(String msg) in B:\ThisFolder\ThisFolder\ThisFolder\Modules\General.cs:line 17
         at Discord.Commands.ModuleClassBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<<BuildCommand>g__ExecuteCallback|0>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Discord.Commands.CommandInfo.ExecuteInternalAsync(ICommandContext context, Object[] args, IServiceProvider services)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
dbug: Discord.Commands.CommandService[0]
      Command: Executed "echo" for ?MyName?#8766 in ThisServer/talk
```

В основном относится к строке -

```
await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(msg);
```

Comment: покажите хоть, что в `msg`

Comment: Вам же прямым текстом в ошибке сказано "401: Unauthorized", то есть сервер говорит вам, что вы неавторизованны, неверный токен или еще что, смотрите внимательно в этом направление.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: msg - это сообщение полученное при написании команды !echo text.
Токен правильный, на сервере бот в онлайне.

Comment: Ошибка говорит об обратном, вам сам сервер дискорда говорит, что вы не авторизованы, не имеете доступа к этому методу. Как минимум, проверьте права бота, как максимум, на странице генерации токена посмотрите какие возможности включены.

Comment: Права у бота максимальные. Вот нашёл тему с похожей проблемой, но её решение мне не помогло.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71398301/discord-net-401-unauthorized-exception
Может ли это как либо связано с типом подключения токена? (Через config / Напрямую)